# create cookies with one script in jquery and access the same cookies with another sccript yui/or anything

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to preserve and get cookies which have been set by a different script? lets say we are migrating the front end functionality from jQuery to yui or some other JS library, can I get the cookies which were saved earlier on the same domain.

Comment: As long as the cookiename and domain are the same: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In the end, the cookies are just text that is made available to javascript. How each library treats those string is independent from the way in which they are stored.